# extjs update the value of a column in all rows in grid

Tags: javascript, extjs

I have created a gridpanel with column 'name' and 'sex' For the toolbar, I have created a combobox of sex. After I select the value of combos 'sex' , the column 'sex' of all rows in the gridpanel will be update to the selected value. How can I update the column of all rows? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is one approach :

```
var store = Ext.getStore('YourGridStore'),
value = yourCombo.getValue();
store.each(function(record){
      record.set('sex',value);
}
//refresh your grid view
```

> Please have a look at 'set' method [Ext.data.Model](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.1/#!/api/Ext.data.Model-method-set)